# What's the best way to call StartPreview() after an image is captured?

Tags: android, camera

Once a call is made to Camera.takePicture(), my preview will stop updating as described in the docs. What's the best way to detect that the image capture process is finished and call startPreview() to make it start updating again?

The call can't be placed in any of the callbacks passed to takePicture, according to the docs, as they should all have returned before I invoke it.

My current best guess is to create a Handler and post a delayed Runnable to it from the JPEG callback (or whichever is the most last defined callback to return).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should start the mCamera.takePicture from within an AsyncTask (or a thread) however AsyncTaks's are the easier option.

A really simple implementation (which of course can be modified) is to:

**The method called to take the picture**

```
/**
 * Execute the AsyncTask that will handle the preview of the captured photo.
 */
public void takePicture() {
    TakePictureTask takePictureTask = new TakePictureTask();
    takePictureTask.execute();
}
```

**The AsyncTask subclass**

```
/**
 * A pretty basic example of an AsyncTask that takes the photo and
 * then sleeps for a defined period of time before finishing. Upon
 * finishing, it will restart the preview - Camera.startPreview().
 */

private class TakePictureTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // This returns the preview back to the live camera feed
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);

        // Sleep for however long, you could store this in a variable and
        // have it updated by a menu item which the user selects.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000); // 3 second preview
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

**The PictureCallback field**

```
private PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        File file = null;

        // Check whether the media is mounted with read/write permission.
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(
                Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            file = getOutputMediaFile();
        }

        if (file == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage persmissions!");
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fileOutputStream.write(data);
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: So, is what they are doing in this tutorial just wrong? http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html I don't really understand how do they restart the preview there, but it looks nothing like AsyncTask or whatever...

Answer (score 12):

Since the PictureCallback is started in a separate thread anyway (it will not lock the UI), you don't need to use an AsyncTask to call the capture.

**There are two ways to do what you want to do, the easiest is the following:**

```
mCamera.startPreview(); //preview has to be started before you can take a picture
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback); //take a picture

private PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        camera.startPreview(); //once your camera has successfully finished
                               //its capture it's safe to restart the preview
        ... //anything else you want to do to process that image
    }
}
```

The second would be using an anonymous function, e.g.:

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback(){
    ...
});
```

Both have their uses, depending on your needs.

Comment: For `PictureCallback` to work on a background thread, camera should be opened in a separate event thread, see [code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19154438/192373).

Comment: @Alex My understanding is that PictureCallback() and PreviewCallback() (which you referenced in your post) operate differently. If you want to do any work on the resulting image from PictureCallback(), use a thread for that.

Please let me know if I'm incorrect in my understanding.

Comment: It's easy to check, but I don't know the answer off hand

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks for your feedback on this, it helped me squeeze a little more performance out of my app.